# Check if Listbox contains a certain element

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I know this question was posted here already multiple times but I've read the threads and nothing works for me so I decided to ask here.

I simply want to check if a certain string is already in my listbox. I've tried the

```
   listBox.Items.Contains("stringToMatch")
```

but I get nothing.

I also tried

```
 foreach (var item in form1.filterTypeList.Items)
                {
                    if (item.ToString() == "stringToMatch")
                    {
                        break;              
                    }
```

He doesn't find anything. Why? How can I solve that?

Comment: Use [ListBox.FindStringExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/81wes5yz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using this way... FindByText

```
strig toMatch = "stringToMatch";
ListItem item = ListBox1.Items.FindByText(toMatch);
if (item != null)
{
    //found
}
else
{
    //not found
}
```

Comment: Does not work. He can't find ListItem and FindByText!

Comment: This is a WPF function but OP uses Winforms!

Answer (score 0):

Please try like below. I am doing for loop on List view items to search string based on item tag or item text.

```
  for (int i = 0; i <= ListView.Items.Count - 1; i++) 
            {
                itmX = ListView.Items.Item(i); 

                if (itmX.Text.ToString() = "stringToMatch")
                {
                  break;              
                } 
            }
```

OR

```
for (int i = 0; i <= ListView.Items.Count - 1; i++) 
    {
        itmX = ListView.Items.Item(i); 

        if (itmX.Tag.ToString() = "stringToMatch")
        {
          break;              
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! In addition to your code, you should post a short explanation about how it addresses the question. For example, what makes this code work where the OP's code failed?

Answer (score 0):

its so simple now , you simply first find the index of that item in the collection of listbox items and then use this fuction of listbox listBox1.FindStringExact  .

```
private void FindMySpecificString(string searchString) 
{ 
   // Ensure we have a proper string to search for. 
   if (searchString != string.Empty) 
   { 
      // Find the item in the list and store the index to the item. 
      int index = listBox1.FindStringExact(searchString); 
      // Determine if a valid index is returned. Select the item if it is valid. 
      if (index != ListBox.NoMatches) 
         listBox1.SetSelected(index,true); 
      else 
         MessageBox.Show("The search string did not find any items in the ListBox that exactly match the specified search string"); 
   } 
}
```

visit the following website for more clarification and examples
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-en/library/81wes5yz(v=vs.110).aspx